# How to create a new xml file with Joox

Tags: java, joox

I'm trying to create a new xml with a structure and at the same time add elements via this

```
String styleName = "myStyle";
String styleKey = "styleKeyValue";

File file = new File("test.xml");        

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.newDocument();

Match x = $(document)
                .namespace("s", "http://www.mycompany.com/data")
                .append(
                    $("Data",
                        $("Styles",
                            $("Style",
                                $("Attributes", "")
                            ).attr("name", styleName)
                        )
                    )
                );

Match xpath = x.xpath("//s:Attributes");

xpath = xpath.append($("Attribute", "").attr("key", styleKey));

x.write(file);
```

However .append doesn't seem to add anything and I end up with an empty file.
This approach is based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15820863/1265200) but the "Document document = $(file).document();" line gives me an exception as the file doesn't exist - hence the use of DocumentBuilder.

Of course I realise that I can create new xml file through a host of other means I am trying to stick with Joox based approach at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working version after feedback from Lucas Eder (Joox "all the way" option)

```
// Initial block to create xml structure
Match x = $("Data",
             $("Styles",
                $("Style",
                    $("Attributes", "")                                            
                 ).attr("name", styleName)
              )
           ).attr("xmlns", "http://www.mycompany.com/data");

// example xpath into structure to add element attribues
// as required
Match xpath = x.xpath("//Attributes");

xpath = xpath.append($("Attribute", "").attr("key", styleKey));

x.write(file);
```

Produces the following:

```
<Data xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/data">
    <Styles>
        <Style name="myStyle">
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute key="styleKeyValue"/>
            </Attributes>
        </Style>
    </Styles>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a misunderstanding of what [`Match.append()`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOOX/javadoc/latest/org/joox/Match.html#append-org.joox.Match...-) does. Let's look at it this way

The [Javadoc](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOOX/javadoc/latest/org/joox/Match.html#append-org.joox.Match...-) reads:

> Append content to the end of each element's content in the set of matched elements.

Now, if you do this:

```
Match x = $(document);
```

This just wraps an existing document in a jOOX [`Match`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOOX/javadoc/latest/org/joox/Match.html) wrapper for further processing. This `Match` wrapper matches no elements at all, because there are no elements in the wrapped `document`, not even a root element (you created a new one). So, in order to actually create a document with elements, you have to:

- Either create the root element using the DOM API
- Or use jOOX all the way, as can be seen below:

  ```
  Match x = $("Data",
              $("Styles",
                $("Style",
                  $("Attributes", "")
                 ).attr("name", styleName)
               )
             );
  ```

Note that your [`Match.namespace()`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOOX/javadoc/latest/org/joox/Match.html#namespace-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) call does not have the effect you'd like it to have. There is currently no way to *set* a namespace on jOOX-generated elements. This is the pending feature request for this feature: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX/issues/133

The `Match.namespace()` method simply binds a namespace to a prefix in the match context, for subsequent `xpath()` calls. Here's the Javadoc extract of the method:

> Get a new Match with added namespace configuration for subsequent XPath calls

Comment: Ok thanks - I understand.  I guess I was expecting a failed match to throw an Exception.  I realise I could have used "if (x.isEmpty())" but that would impede the method chaining style.  I have revised my code along the lines (joox all the way option) you suggest and got it working - will add as an edit to the question..

Comment: @Dazed: Great idea, btw you can provide your own answer here on stack overflow. It's the recommended way to suggest your final solution, rather than editing the question for that...